# How to validate a string in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have a textarea where a user can bulk add clients. In the textarea they would add the clients like this

```
client 1,client1@domain.com,client username 1
client 2,client2@domain.com,client username 2
client 3,client3@domain.com,client username 3
```

Here is what I have so far

```
    public function bulkClients()
    {
        $bulk =  request('bulk_clients');
        $split = explode("\n",$bulk);

        foreach($split as $row)
        {
            $split_row = explode(",", $row);
            $name = $split_row[0];
            $email = $split_row[1];
            $username = $split_row[2];

            $validate = Validator::make($email, [
                $email => 'email',
                $username => 'unique:App\User,username'
            ]);

            if($validate->fails())
            {
                $messages = $validate->messages();

                return response()->json([
                    'messages' => $messages
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
```

What I would like to know is how can I validate that `$email` is an email or that `$username` is unique.

Comment: The first parameter is the data and the second parameter is the rules. For username, you should use ```unique:users,username```

Answer (score 0):

The first param of Validator::make should be an array and the second is the rules for the keys of the array.

```php
    public function bulkClients()
    {
        $bulk =  request('bulk_clients');
        $split = explode("\n",$bulk);

        foreach($split as $row)
        {
            $split_row = explode(",", $row);
            $client['name'] = $split_row[0];
            $client['email'] = $split_row[1];
            $client['username'] = $split_row[2];

            $validate = Validator::make($client, [
                'email' => 'email',
                'username' => 'unique:App\User,username'
            ]);

            if($validate->fails())
            {
                $messages = $validate->messages();

                return response()->json([
                    'messages' => $messages
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You find all available rules in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-string):

```
$validate = Validator::make([ 'email' => $split_row[1],
                             'username' => $split_row[2]
               ], [
                'email' => 'string',
                'username' => 'unique:App\User,username'
            ]);
```

However, for email, I would rather check if its a valid email instead of a string. Thus,

```
'email' => 'email'
```

would be recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the validator for the whole array instead of validating it row by row:

```php
$clients = Str::of(request()->get('bulk_clients'))
    ->explode("\n")
    ->map(fn ($value) => Str::of($value)->explode(','))
    ->toArray();

$validator = Validator::make(compact('clients'), [
    'clients'     => 'array',
    'clients.*.0' => 'required|string',
    'clients.*.1' => 'required|email',
    'clients.*.2' => 'required|unique:App\User,username',
]);
```